# Sheadawson Silverstripe Blocks: Blocks within blocks

Tags: php, class, block, silverstripe, data-objects

I'm using Shea Dawson's silverstripe blocks module and I'm wondering if there's a way to have blocks within blocks?

For example: I'm trying to create a "Grid" Block, and within that grid block I'd like the user to be able to "Add a block". Essentially, this "Grid Block" will act like a "Block Area".

I'm on the most recent version of SS, and this module. Let me know if you need any further information...

Comment: Sounds like you need a WidgetArea which you can add blocks/widgets to. Side note: dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental does this with "elements". I previously looked at this module and ended up going with elemental for this same reason.

Comment: @RobbieAverill Hey mate, thanks for the response. Yeah, essentially I want the users to be able to drop Block Areas wherever they want on a page. I have an idea for a "Grid Block Area" but this might be within the footer block area, or the Main Content area. Basically I want to have full width blocks which stretch the width of the screen, and blocks that are contained to a grid.

Comment: I modified the module for nested blocks, its quite functional. I can post my solution but I modified it for $has_one $has_many relation. Thye importnat thing is to maintain the relation to the parent page even in nested blocks, especially if you want search to link to the page correctly.